# HOWTO do CSRF protection in Struts2 application for AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have a struts2 webapp in which I need to implement CSRF protection. For statis forms it is pretty straight forward. I just need to activate the `tokenSession` interceptor & then set `<s:token/>` in the form to be submitted. (explained [here](http://nickcoblentz.blogspot.com/2008/11/csrf-prevention-in-struts-2.html) and [here](http://web.securityinnovation.com/appsec-weekly/blog/bid/84318/Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-CSRF-Prevention-Using-Struts-2))

But the problem appears when I need to enable CSRF protection for POST AJAX calls (I am using jQuery) which are not necessarily submitted via forms. I face the issue of re-using token when making subsequent AJAX calls.

Any pointers or different approaches are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I have resolved the issue by generating tokens for AJAX requests and sending it with the normal response like so -

```
    Map<String, String> tokenInfo = Maps.newHashMap();
    tokenInfo.put("struts.token.name", TokenHelper.getTokenName());
    tokenInfo.put(TokenHelper.getTokenName(), TokenHelper.setToken());
```

I will abstract out a util method out of this & have the Actions that are token-activated to return this as part of response for actions which will be executed repeatedly without refresh of the page.

I am still looking for an elegant solution to this though.

Comment: We are facing this issue too. Did you find better solutions? Also., can you explain more about your solution? Do you make any changes in JSP files too.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you generate a Token and use it as parameter in the ajax call ?

For the subsequent AJAX calls, you can use a `per-user Token`,

not necessarily a `per-request Token`,

as explained in this SO answer: [Do I need a CSRF token for jQuery .ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089909/do-i-need-a-csrf-token-for-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks but I was thinking of all also preventing double submits as well. "Per user" approach will not help that much for that.