# Is CSRF a threat if I only send JSON to my server?

Tags: jquery, json, security, csrf

I send JSON to my server from browsers using [`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`.

Is CSRF a concern here? (I know it's an issue if I send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data from forms.)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089909/do-i-need-a-csrf-token-for-jquery-ajax. if you use a authentication cookie.

Comment: @Mawi12345 I don't think this is a duplicate because I believe using JSON makes a big difference to the answer. The question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008469/are-json-web-services-vulnerable-to-csrf-attacks but doesn't address jQuery specifically.

Comment: the link you provided should answer your question. jquery ajax is a wrapper of XHR.

Comment: So the answer is it's not a concern if I don't have any `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers and don't allow others to inject scripts into my web page?

Comment: [Similar question/answer here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/84713/8340)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `application/json` and your server does not allow cross-origin requests then the only threat comes from XHR-based CSRF attacks. So the attacker need to use XSS (or similar attacks) to run code from your origin.